# Bootstrap Modal not fading properly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a few bootstrap modals since a few days. Last days all work's fine but today I don't know how, the fade `animation` when the `modal show/hide` didn't work. You can see live example [here](http://residenciarucab.es/rucab/inscripciones.php) (Click on ver precios, for example). It shows/hide without animation. The structure that I use on the link is something like:

```
<a href="#" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalavisolegal-footer">Aviso legal</a>
```

And the modal structure:

```
   <div class="modal fade modalCondiciones modal-politicas" id="modalavisolegal-footer" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalavisolegal-footer" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">AVISO LEGAL</h5>
                    <span aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</span>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="texto-condiciones">
<p>En cumplimiento de la Ley 34/2002 de Servicios de la Sociedad de la Información y de Comercio Electrónico de España, le informamos que esta página web es propiedad de Fundación CB, en adelante Residencia Universitaria J. A. Marcos Blanco (RUCAB), con domicilio en Calle Pablo Sorozábal Nº 1, 06006, Badajoz, España, con CIF G06035448.
Para cualquier consulta, nos puede contactar por info@residenciarucab.es. El sitio web www.residenciarucab.es, en adelante el PORTAL, se rige por la normativa exclusivamente aplicable en España, quedando sometida a ella, tanto nacionales como extranjeros que utilicen este sitio web.
</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is it normal that you have 2 href in your link? :)

Comment: animation works just fine in the link

Comment: That live example works perfectly fine for me